# WP_Query count posts - custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, count

how i can count from a custom post type the entries?

```
<ul class="test">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'schusslersalz', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<li>';
the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
the_content();
echo '</li>';
endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

how can i count the entries from "schusslersalz" in a number and display it. 
I have serch and found the funciton:

```
$count = $loop->post_count;
```

how i use this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `wp_count_posts` function has parameter `$type` for post type to count, you should use this parameter if you want to count the number of `schusslersalz`

A snippet

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'schusslersalz' )->publish;
echo $count_posts;
```

Full snippet as follow:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'schusslersalz'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $the_query->found_posts;
```

Hope I helped

Answer (score 3):

Try this,
`$loop->found_posts;`

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to count total post including pagination post

```
<?php  global $wp_query
 $count = $wp_query->found_posts;
echo $count; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'custom_post_type' )->publish;
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function wpb_total_posts() { 
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'grants',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'application_deadline',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>'
            )),);
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $the_query->found_posts;
}
add_shortcode('total_posts','wpb_total_posts');
```